# Able to test AAA to Radius Server from router but unable to log into Router with A.D

Tags: cisco-ios, cisco-commands, aaa, radius

I am having issue with setting up my Radius server to authenticate before going to the router. I am able to do a test from the router successfully but once I exit the router and log in with my Windows Active Directory group login (same one used during the test inside the router), it says that the password is incorrect. Below are few screen shots of what I have configure. Is there something I am missing? Please advise. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which application are you using to log into the router? The router will prompt for a username and password, and it will use what you enter at the prompts to authenticate with the RADIUS server. Some applications let you automate logging into the router with a script.

Comment: Sounds like an 802.1X error,, MAC addresses missing? improper configuration?

Comment: Don't use RADIUS for admin AAA into networking devices.  Use TACACS.  See http://tacacs.net/docs/TACACS_Advantages.pdf

Comment: Dang. I have this exact same problem on a Catalyst 4507 and I was about to ask this question. If I fix it I'll post an answer.